# ASP Calendar control like Google's calendar

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I'm going to start working on project developed in ASP.NET.

In this project I need to show the data in a month calender like Google's calendar or something like that.

So my question is:
Is there any control I can use to do this thing?
If not, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(VS.80).aspx) control in ASP.NET which offers some basic functionality that you may take a look at. There's also a [calendar extension](http://329868.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) in the AJAX Control Toolkit.

Comment: thanx Darin

but unfortunately i can't add any data to these calenders. 

i want to write some info under any day.

as far as i know it is not possible with the current Calender control in ASP.NET

Comment: Abdulrhman, you most certainly can add data to the basic Calendar server control.

Look at the OnDayRender event.  You would add data there.  You have total access to the cell in that event.